# OpenLayers cannot close popup

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, popup

I am using OpenLayers 2.

I have a map with points from GeoJSON file.
I created a default style and a select style for these points.
I created a popup with attributes from GeoJSON when clicking on a point.
All works fine, except that I can't close the popup: the point is unselected, but the popup still remains even if I use the red cross.
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481764/openlayers-unable-to-close-popup-when-added-using-call-from-outside-map) that seems to deal with the same issue, but I can't use it in my application.

code for popup :

```
selection = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(operationCentroide);

    operationCentroide.events.on({
        "featureselected": monpopup,
        "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
    });

    map.addControl(selection);
    selection.activate();

    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        selection.unselectAll();
    }

    function monpopup(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        var contenu = feature.attributes.numope;
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
            contenu,
            null, true, onPopupClose);
            map.addPopup(popup);
    }

    function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it : I just deleted onPopupClose from popup definition in function monpopup(event). Now white cross does its job